# Bash exponentiation limit

Tags: bash, exponential

I want to understand the reason maximum value for `$[a**b]` operation in Bash.

```
$ echo $[2**62]
4611686018427387904
$ echo $[2**63]
-9223372036854775808
$ echo $[2**64]
0
```

Comment: Side note: `$[...]` is super old and deprecated, you should use `$((...))` instead. The Bash manual doesn't even mention `$[...]` any longer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic) in the Bash manual:

> Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers with no check for overflow

So, on a 64-bit platform, for a signed integer, we wrap around at 2<sup>63</sup>:

```
$ echo $((2**63-1))
9223372036854775807
$ echo $((2**63))
-9223372036854775808
```